# Start ppp(Mobile broadband) connection automatically when eth0 gets down

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband

I am having a two connection. One is local area Ethernet connection which connects to internet. Second connection is a GSM modem connected to my modem.

What I am looking for is,

1. When eth0(local network) is down, start automatically ppp connection
2. When eth0 is up, turn off automatically ppp connection.

So in a way I am looking for continous internet connect and priority is through eth0(local area network)

I believe this can be done by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` file. But I don't know exactly what to do.

I can configure my modem based ppp connection using pon/poff command.

Answer (score 0):

Network-manager will do this for you, so why are you not using it? I'm using it in exactly this way to prioritize wired over wifi and wifi over 3g.

Comment: Could you please provide more details and also see if you can help here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/271802/how-do-i-force-applications-to-use-different-internet-connections