# How do I force applications to use different internet connections?

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet

I have two data connections. One is a USB Dongle with a high speed, limited data plan. The other is a broadband (over WiFi) slower, but unlimited data plan, connection. I want certain applications such as `Software Updates` to use only the WiFi connection for downloading whereas my browsers (Chromium, Firefox) to use the high speed connection.

Is it possible to force this selection on the applications ?

Also, in case one of the connections is not available, then everything should fall back on the other connection.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in the way you describe, but you can get somewhere by manually adding routes. Say you use archive.ubuntu.com, you can add a route for 91.189.92.0/24 to go via the wifi and leave the default route to be the dongle.